# Keeping track of count in my recursive function(Collatz)

Tags: c++, recursion, collatz

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to keep track of the amount of times my recursive function calls itself while performaing collatz function. I have the function definition:

```
template<class myType>
myType recursionSet<myType>::collatz(myType n)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    else {
        if(n%2 == 1)
            return collatz(3*n+1);
        else
            return collatz(n/2);
    }
}
```

how can i keep track of the number of times this function calls itself? I cannot seem for the life of me to come up with a solution. Thanks!

reference to collatz function: http://www.xamuel.com/collatz-recursion/

Comment: pass the count in as an argument, or make it a static.

Comment: @Serdalis Wont a static variable in a recursive function not work? The variable will never be reset, and there is no way to set it equal to zero at any point as it would repeatedly set itself to zero every time it calls itself.

Comment: @Need4Sleep You never mentioned anything about any more than one initial entry, and in that case a static will work correctly. Otherwise use a by-reference count parameter.

Comment: Yes, I think the static would be problematic. Passing it as an argument is what you want.

Comment: yes, a static would be problematic since you'd have to have a case to reset it too, just giving options :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compute the length of the Collatz chain, aren't you.  Do you realise that currently you always return `1`?  You should modify your code to return the count instead.  That means adding the current iteration to the recursive call:

```
template<class myType>
myType recursionSet<myType>::collatz(myType n)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    else {
        if(n%2 == 1)
            return 1 + collatz(3*n+1);
        else
            return 1 + collatz(n/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, I was just thinking about this when your answer popped up. Makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: No problem...  And since I predict you're now going to try to compute the longest Collatz chain with a starting value of less than 1,000,000 I suggest you memoize the calls by supplying a `vector` reference. ;-)